# Canvas blocky font rendering in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas, antialiasing

i want to draw Blocky Font *(Atari-Like)* on a big Canvas. I have already made a Canvas which copies the rendered scene from a small 40-by-40 pixel canvas. But it looks like the Font is smoothed-out by the small canvas. **How can I disable that?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it, needed to use `ctx.fillText` instead of `ctx.strokeText`.

Answer (score 0):

Could it be you ar looking for

```
ctx.imageSmoothingEnabled = true; // Blurs pixels when enlarging and blend pixels when zooming out.

ctx.imageSmoothingEnabled = false; // zoomed in pixels remain square with hard edges 
                                   // like in 8 bit games.
                                   // uses nearest pixel when zoomed out.
```

With image smoothing off some devices have better performance. There does not seem to be a performance penalty turning this flag on an off.